# Not getting the Total Amount(Without VAT)

Tags: c#

```
Country: Bahrain( i am selecting)
Amount:1000
Bank charges: 100(i am entering)
Vat:5%(entering)            result:50(autogenerate)
Discount:6%(entering)        result:60(autogenerate)
Total:1070(autogenerate)
```

This is working fine.I am getting the Total(with VAT).

```
    Country:India(i am selecting)
    Amount:1000
    Bank charges: 100(i am entering)
    Discount:5%(entering)        result:50(autogenerate)
    Total:(here i am not getting the amount)(may be because i set the visibility of VAT field false)
```

Here i am hidding the field VAT by using vattr.Visible=false. What should i do in order to sort out this issue?

Code behind:

```
protected void lstCountryy_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (lstCountryy.SelectedItem.Text == "U.A.E" || lstCountryy.SelectedItem.Text == "BAHRAIN" || lstCountryy.SelectedItem.Text=="SAUDI ARABIA")
        {

            vattr.Visible = true;
            trdeclaration.Visible = false;

        }
        else
        {

            vattr.Visible = false;
            trdeclaration.Visible = true;
        }
    }
```

Javascript:

```
function calculate(amount) {
            var bankcharge = document.getElementById("<%=txtBankCharge.ClientID%>").value;
            var vat = document.getElementById("<%=txtvatt.ClientID%>").value;
          var discount = document.getElementById("<%=txtDiscount.ClientID%>").value;

            var sum = 0;

            $(".amt").each(function () {

                if  (isNaN(this.value))
                {
                    alert("Please enter numbers only");
                    return false;
                }

                if (!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length != 0) {
                    sum += parseFloat(this.value);

                }

            });


            if (bankcharge.length > 0) {
                if (isNaN(bankcharge)) {
                    alert("Bank charge should be numbers only !!");
                    return false;
                }
                else {
                    sum = sum + parseFloat(bankcharge);
                }
            }

            if (vat.length > 0)
            {
                if (isNaN(vat)) {
                    alert("VAT should be numbers only !!");
                    return false;
                }
                else {
                    sum = sum + parseFloat(vat);
                }
            }


            if (discount.length > 0) {
                if (isNaN(discount)) {
                    alert("Discount amount should be numbers only !!");
                    return false;
                }
                else {
                    sum = sum - parseFloat(discount);
                }
            }
            var atemp = sum.toString().split(".");
            if (atemp.length > 1) {
                sum = sum.toFixed(2);
            }
             document.getElementById("<%=txtTotal.ClientID%>").value = sum;
            document.getElementById("<%=txtAmountInWords.ClientID%>").value = convertNumberToWords(sum);
        }



        function vatCalc()//added by chetan
        {
            var sum = 0;

            $(".amt").each(function () {

                if (isNaN(this.value)) {
                    alert("Please enter numbers only");
                    return false;
                }

                if (!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length != 0) {
                    sum += parseFloat(this.value);

                }

            });

        var _txt2 = document.getElementById('<%= txtvat.ClientID %>');
        var _txt3 = document.getElementById('<%= txtvatt.ClientID %>');
        var t1=0, t2=0;

        //if(_txt1.value != "") t1=_txt1.value;
        if(_txt2.value != "") t2=_txt2.value;

        _txt3.value = (sum * parseFloat(t2) )/ 100;

        }

        function discountCalc()
        {
             var sum = 0;

            $(".amt").each(function () {

                if (isNaN(this.value)) {
                    alert("Please enter numbers only");
                    return false;
                }

                if (!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length != 0) {
                    sum += parseFloat(this.value);

                }

            });

        var _txt2 = document.getElementById('<%= txtDiscountText.ClientID %>');
        var _txt3 = document.getElementById('<%= txtDiscount.ClientID %>');
        var t1=0, t2=0;

        //if(_txt1.value != "") t1=_txt1.value;
        if(_txt2.value != "") t2=_txt2.value;

        _txt3.value = (sum * parseFloat(t2)) / 100;

        }
```

The problem is here:

```
 if (vat.length > 0)
            {
                if (isNaN(vat)) {
                    alert("VAT should be numbers only !!");
                    return false;
                }
                else {
                    sum = sum + parseFloat(vat);
                }
            }
```

I wanted to write this condition in such a way that when use selects bahrain,vat should be visible and should be calculated.
when user selects india,vat should be hidden and will yield the total amount.

Comment: Forget your problem and read your question as if you were us.  See if you can solve it.  When you can't, read the FAQ about how to ask questions.

Comment: I agree with the previous comment. That said, what's really needed here is a [mcve]. English is a hard way to explain technical issues even for a native speaker, and for a non-native it can be near impossible at times. But code is universal.

Comment: @Sam Axe What wrong i asked?

Answer (score 0):

Finally i got solution.This w orked perfectly.

```
 if (lstCountryy.SelectedValue == "U.A.E" || lstCountryy.SelectedValue == "BAHRAIN" || lstCountryy.SelectedValue == "SAUDI ARABIA")
                {


                    txtvat.Text = "";
                    txtvatt.Text = "";
                    txtBankCharge.Text = "";
                    txtDiscount.Text = "";
                    txtDiscountText.Text = "";
                    txtTotal.Text = "";

                    vattr.Style.Add("display", "float");
                    trdeclaration.Visible = false;

                    //txtvat.Enabled = true;

                }
                else
                {
                    txtvat.Text = "";
                    txtvatt.Text = "";
                    txtBankCharge.Text = "";
                    txtDiscount.Text = "";
                    txtDiscountText.Text = "";
                    txtTotal.Text = "";


                    vattr.Style.Add("display", "none");



                    trdeclaration.Visible = true;
                }
```